# PHP Parse URL From Current URL

Tags: php

I am trying to parse url and extract value from it .My url value is `www.mysite.com/register/?referredby=admin`. I want to get value `admin` from this url. For this, I have written following code. Its giving me value `referredby=admin`, but I want only `admin` as value. How Can I achieve this? Below is my code:

```
<?php 
    $url = $current_url="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    setcookie('ref_by', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
    echo $_COOKIE['ref_by'];

 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is not a really clean solution, but you can try something like:

```
$url = "MYURL";
$parse = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parse['query']);

echo $referredby; // same name of the get param (see parse_str doc)
```

---

> [PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php): **Warning**
>
> Using this function without the result parameter is highly DISCOURAGED and DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.
>
> Dynamically setting variables in function's scope suffers from exactly same problems as register_globals.
>
> Read section on security of Using Register Globals explaining why it is dangerous.

Comment: The manual explicitly states that using [`parse_str`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php), without the result parameter is **discouraged** and will be **deprecated** with v7.2. Stating: *"Dynamically setting variables in function's scope suffers from exactly same problems as register_globals."*

Comment: That's why i said that is not clean and to check doc

Comment: But why then show this type of usage, when the correct way is also explained on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) function.

```
$url = "www.mysite.com/register/?email=admin";
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['email'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```html
$url = "www.mysite.com/register/?referredby=admin";
$parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($parse, $output);
echo $output['referredby'];
```

Comment: it's working also in php 7.2. I have solution for same

Comment: Sure. And then you can never update, becasue this will break. When functions are marked as deprecated (ánd discouraged), you should not use them and should also try to find replacements for current code when you encounter these functions.

Comment: Check the updated code using with session for get the value from query string

Comment: Apologies, I read the warning slightly too quick. Removed the warning and downvote, as it is indeed not wrong if implemented this way

Comment: @Martijin Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$referred = $_GET['referredby'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$referred = "referredby=admin";
$pieces = explode("=", $referred);
echo $pieces[1]; // admin
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I will make sure to explain the reason for this answer next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant for you, but maybe it is for others: I've recently released a composer package for parsing urls (https://www.crwlr.software/packages/url). Using that library you can do it like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/register/?referredby=admin';
$query = Crwlr\Url\Url::parse($url)->queryArray();
echo $query['referredby'];
```

The parse method parses the url and returns an object, the queryArray method returns the url query as array.